# Permissions not getting assigned from parent directory when creating new sub directory

Tags: permissions, chmod

The issue for me when we I create a new subdirectory , it is not copying the execute permissions for group from parent directory . Permissions are as follows:

Parent Directory:

```
$ ls -ld  /data/share/web/myportal/myLogos/
drwxrwsr-x 66 root admin 4096 Nov  1 10:08 /data/share/web/myportal/myLogos/
```

New Sub Directory permissions:

```
$ ls -ld /data/share/web/myportal/myLogos/6002526/
drwxrwSr-x 2 tomcat admin 4096 Nov  1 17:10 /data/share/web/myportal/myLogos/6002526/
```

If we see above , execute for group is missing. I need to manually put execute permissions for group user .

umask value is as follows for root user.

```
# umask
0022
# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

Any suggestions how to fix this  ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, can you expand on what you mean by 'check whether -R was set before setting permissions for parent directory' - which command do you expect the -R to have been set on?

Comment: Sorry , I updated the question . It is chmod with -R option .